# In C#, what does the following syntax do: ((Classname)this.variableName).property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Here is the actual line of code I'm looking at:

```
ContentVersionCache cvc = ((PageBase)this.Page).cache;
```

I know this is a really basic question but I've just started learning C# so go easy on me :)

Cheers
Iain

Comment: Thanks all for the responses, you've all been very helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Break it up into smaller pieces:

```
(PageBase)this.Page
```

Casts `this.Page` to a `PageBase`. This means treating `this.Page` as if it were a `PageBase`, even though it may not be declared as such. If it isn't, then this will throw a runtime `InvalidCastException`!

```
().cache
```

Access the `cache` property or field of the `PageBase`.

```
ContentVersionCache cvc = cache;
```

Store the cache to a local variable called cvc.

Comment: A very detailed and helpful response. Well done sir! Have a green tick :)

Comment: That's funny because I always figured I'd never have the patience to be a teacher.

Answer (score 2):

It casts the this.Page to a PageBase class .

Answer (score 1):

**this.Page** is casted to **PageBase** class then assign its cache property to **ContentVersionCache** instance **cvc**

Answer (score 0):

it convert this.Page to PageBase class and then call cache and assign it's value to cvc